# CSharp Timer Problems

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

My Timer doesn't work as expected, why is the pictureBox moving faster after each call of the Timer interval.

I want the pictureBox to move frequent over the Form after someone pressed the D button. The functions add and remove Event works fine so that can't be the case:

```
    Timer loop;
    Int32 posX, posY;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        loop = new Timer();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sprit.Enabled = false;
        loop.Interval = 10;
        posX = this.sprit.Location.X;
        posY = this.sprit.Location.Y;
    }

    private void nextStep(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        posX++;
        this.sprit.Location = new Point(posX, posY);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode) {
            case Keys.D:
                addEvent(nextStep);
                loop.Start();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.D:
                removeEvent(nextStep);
                loop.Stop();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add your timer_Tick event?

Comment: Which part of the code is problematic exactly?

Comment: nextStep is the Tick event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form1_KeyDown` will be called repeatedly as long as you hold the key, so you keep calling `addEvent(nextStep)`.

Try calling `addEvent(nextStep)` only once on `Form1_KeyDown`